# for $n \ge 3$, $S_n$ is isomorphic to its group of inner automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How would I go about showing that for $n \ge 3$, $S_n$ is isomorphic to its group of inner automorphisms?

Comment: Note that $G/Z(G) \equiv Inn(G)$, where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$, so one way to show that $S_n \equiv Inn(S_n)$ would be to show that $S_n$ has trivial center.

Comment: Maybe interesting: https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/05/22/for-all-n-except-6-every-automorphism-of-symn-is-inner/, http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/AutGroups.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

We first prove a lemma.

**Lemma.** If $n \ge 3$, $S_n$ has trivial center.

*Proof.* Let $\sigma \in S_n$. Assume $\sigma(1) = k$. Choose a permutation $\tau \in S_n$ such that $\tau(1) = 1$ and $\tau(k) \neq k$. Then $\sigma\tau(1) = \sigma(1) = k$ but $\tau\sigma(1) = \tau(k) \neq k$. So $\tau$ does not commute with $\sigma$. It follows that $\sigma$ cannot be in the center of $S_n$. Because $\sigma$ was arbitrary, the center must be trivial. $\square$

By the lemma, the group of inner automorphisms is isomorphic to $S_n/Z(S_n) \cong S_n$.